# JDBC, Socket factory not found while using mariadb driver

Tags: java, jdbc, osgi, mariadb, apache-felix

So, basically, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/SocketFactory`
 while trying to connect to my database. I'm using mariadb driver from mvn repo.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my code:

```
 try{
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver());
    }catch (SQLException e){
        logService.log(LogService.LOG_ERROR, "Error while registering driver.");
    }


    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://myhost:myport/mydb?allowMultiQueries=true", "admin", "password")) {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
```

Is there something wrong with my code or configuration?

Edit: full stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/SocketFactory
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.standardSocket(Utils.java:138)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.socket.SocketUtility.lambda$getSocketHandler$1(SocketUtility.java:44)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.createSocket(Utils.java:603)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:483)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1195)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:560)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:174)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:92)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.killbill.billing.plugin.custom.api.dao.InvoiceRepository.getInvoice(InvoiceRepository.java:53)
    at org.killbill.billing.plugin.custom.api.api.controllers.GetInvoiceController.getResult(GetInvoiceController.java:49)
    at org.killbill.billing.plugin.custom.api.api.controllers.GetInvoiceController.getResult(GetInvoiceController.java:20)
    at org.killbill.billing.plugin.custom.api.api.CustomApiServlet.forward(CustomApiServlet.java:105)
    at org.killbill.billing.plugin.custom.api.api.CustomApiServlet.validate(CustomApiServlet.java:74)
    at org.killbill.billing.plugin.custom.api.api.CustomApiServlet.doPost(CustomApiServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.killbill.billing.osgi.ContextClassLoaderHelper$ClassLoaderInvocationHandler$1.execute(ContextClassLoaderHelper.java:144)
    at org.killbill.commons.profiling.Profiling.executeWithProfiling(Profiling.java:33)
    at org.killbill.billing.osgi.ContextClassLoaderHelper$ClassLoaderInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(ContextClassLoaderHelper.java:141)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.killbill.billing.osgi.http.OSGIServlet.serviceViaPlugin(OSGIServlet.java:86)
    at org.killbill.billing.osgi.http.OSGIServlet.doPost(OSGIServlet.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.killbill.billing.jaxrs.resources.PluginResource.serviceViaOSGIPlugin(PluginResource.java:187)
    at org.killbill.billing.jaxrs.resources.PluginResource.serviceViaOSGIPlugin(PluginResource.java:171)
    at org.killbill.billing.jaxrs.resources.PluginResource.doPOST(PluginResource.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at org.killbill.billing.server.security.TenantFilter.handleAuthenticationError(TenantFilter.java:119)
    at org.killbill.billing.server.security.TenantFilter.doFilter(TenantFilter.java:88)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.killbill.billing.server.filters.ResponseCorsFilter.doFilter(ResponseCorsFilter.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.SocketFactory not found by org.kill-bill.billing.plugin.java.custom-api [20]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel done, please, have a look.

Comment: Are you using OSGi?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, we do. Does it affect my case?

Comment: Well, the error suggest that you are using a OSGi classloader which can't find `javax.net.SocketFactory`, even though it is part of Java itself. I have never done anything with OSGi, so I can't really help with solving this though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the hint, I will look into this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `javax.net` package wasn't included in the OSGi bundle. It caused a lot of confusion since we used MySQL JDBC driver before and I suppose it has it's own implementation of `SocketFactory`, which MariaDB driver apparently hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a jdk and that the jdk is not corrupted. It must contain the jsse.jar in the jdk1.8.0_xyz\jre\lib dir. See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsse-136410.html for manual download (this should not be necessary in a clean installation and I'd rather re-install the jdk).

Answer (score 0):

This is solved but in case someone else goes through the same error.

If you get this error in your plugin you can just import **javax.net** under the  tag of your pom file.